# Not able to add a "Config Transform" to my web.config file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web.config-transform

I'm trying to add a "Config Transform" to my web.config file as explained here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

When I right click on my web.config file, "Add Config Transform" is not even an option.

I found instruction on how to modify my .csproj file to make it so I can add a "Config Transform" here:

https://gist.github.com/EdCharbeneau/9135216

but when I try to unload my project to get at the .csproj file to make the changes I don't have the option of unloading my project.

I am at a loss. Can someone clue me in to what is going wrong?

Comment: You state that you have a .csproj file, but yet it's tagged with vb.net.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I mean that when I searched for what to do after I could not add a Config Transform I came across the page that says to edit the .csproj file. The directions to get at the .csproj file is to unload your project then right click on it and select "edit .csproj", but when I try to unload my project I don't have the option of unloading the project. for all intents and purposes it looks like I don't have a .csproj file.

Comment: OH, I see what you are saying now. Because I'm using vb.net I shouldn't have a .csproj file in the first place. Right?

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about all that.  Use Notepad or Notepad++ and just edit the file manually.

Comment: edit what file? i don't have a .csproj.

Comment: vbproj is the VB.Net equivalent.